# sql split issue from a string having more than 2 '-', and i have to fetch all data whatever their is present after 2'-'

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

i have to fetch model no. col data from ivm col. data.

| ivm | model no |
| --- | --- |
| 534643-240-0671258 | 0671258 |
| 2894262-101107-V5009-L | V5009-L |
| 732189-149-NV51K6650SS | NV51K6650SS |
| 1139081-97531-PB1100PS1 | PB1100PS1 |
| 89234-79794-T10358-4-CP | T10358-4-CP |
| 2591217-104703-AGAKN95 | AGAKN95 |
| 793509-81227-79246-RB | 79246-RB |

Comment: MySQL != BigQuery ... what is your actual database?

Comment: On MySQL - use [`REGEXP_REPLACE(ivm, '^([^-]+-){2}', '')`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

Answer (score 0):

On BigQuery we can try using `REGEXP_EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT ivm, REGEXP_EXTRACT(ivm, r'(?:[^-]+-){2}(.*)') AS model_no
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern used:

```regex
(?:[^-]+-){2}  match ABC123-DEF456- (i.e. first 2 terms)
(.*)           then capture everything else which follows
```

Comment: can you share me some documents if you have about how you wrote "r'(?:[^-]+-){2}(.*)')"

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery) - I think in this option regexp is much easier to swallow :o) - it just looks for two groups of digits at the beginning and simply removes them - leaving exactly what you are looking for  - which is the rest of string

```
select ivm, regexp_replace(ivm, r'^\d+-\d+-', '') as  model_no
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]